# FAQ tag is illegible on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

You can view this simply by going here: https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq

Comment: Without zooming, some of tags are hard to read on an iPad.

Answer (score 1):

now fixed pending deploy!